# md-on-demand inside md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, infinite-scroll, md-autocomplete

As stated Angular-Material md-autocomplete's [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete#notes):

> The md-autocomplete uses the the md-virtual-repeat directive for displaying the results inside of the dropdown.

I've faced with a problem that I can't find any snippet how can I use virtual repeat inside of autocomplete.

I understand that I have to use a specific structure for infinite scroll according to md-virtual-repeat's [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat#attributes).

I have md-autocomplete:

```
<md-autocomplete
            md-no-cache="true"
            md-selected-item="obj.selectedItem"
            md-search-text="obj.searchText"
            md-items="item in infiniteItems"
            md-item-text="item.name"
            md-on-demand>
            <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="obj.searchText" md-highlight-flags="i">{{item.name}}</span>
            </md-item-template>
            <md-not-found>
                not found!
            </md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
```

And I have infiniteItems object, according to md-virtual-repeat suggestions:

```
$scope.infiniteItems = {
        numLoaded_: 0,
        toLoad_: 0,
        items: [],

        getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
            if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
                this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                return null;
            }

            return this.items[index];
        },

        getLength: function() {
            return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
        },

        fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {

            if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                this.toLoad_ += 20;
                restService.getData().then(angular.bind(this, function(response) {
                    this.items = this.items.concat(response.data);
                    this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

As result rest load data first time after loading entire page, and when I try to type smth I get mesage "not found" and dropdown with loaded data even do not open.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `md-autocomplete` tag attribute, change

```
md-items="item in infiniteItems"
```

to

```
md-items="item in infiniteItems.items"
```

and you should be able to see auto complete list.